# Why do freestyle outlines occasionally have gaps?

Tags: rendering, freestyle

Sometimes freestyle renders will have gaps in the lines:

[image]

Closer up:

[image]

What causes this and how can I prevent it?

Comment: You can improve the result by giving te stroke a round end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Make the mesh smooth (I guess this has been already done in your scene).
2. Enable the *Face Smoothness* option in *Properties > Render Layers > Freestyle*.

A detailed explanation of these settings can be found [here](http://freestyleintegration.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/weekly-update-november-15-28/).

Comment: This seems to work :) Could you explain what you mean by "Make the mesh smooth"? (smooth shading? physically smooth?)

Comment: By "make the mesh smooth" I meant smooth shading.  This way mesh vertices may have multiple normals, from which Freestyle can compute smooth silhouette lines that do not exist as edges in the original mesh data.

Answer (score 4):

It is mainly caused by toggling "Chaining" feature in the Freestyle Lining Style panel, if you are sure it's not caused by any Freestyle modifiers.

If so, to prevent that, you may simply toggle "Enable Chaining" off, or just include "Contour" by toggling it in the Edge Types list. (But make sure "Same Object" is not toggled, which is right below the "Enable Chaining" checkbox.)

Comment: This seems to remove some of the gaps, but not all: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/62245

Comment: Agree. user1561's way works better on your scene.

Answer (score 0):

## For Text (fonts)

1. Convert the text to a mesh using **Alt + C** in **3D View** and picking **"Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text"**

[image: converter menu]

2. Turn on **"Face Smoothness"** in **Properties > Render Layers > Freestyle**

[image: Face Smoothness setting]

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Note: this might still not be enough, you might be forced to apply **"Smooth"** Faces in **Edit mode** (press **TAB** in **3D View** to switch) in the **Shading/UVs** sidebar (press **T** to open).

Since this might screw up the rendering of the model, you might want to duplicate the model and render the copy on another layer.