# Freestyle External Contour has Large Gaps. Error Related to Topology?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, edges, freestyle

[image: The Problem I'm encountering with Freestyle line renders.]

Large Gaps appearing in external contour. I've disabled any modifiers and have troubleshot the issue extensively using other "gap fix" procedures & recommendations. Error appears to occur at very acute angles, but line-render isn't tied to occluded freestyle edges. Error somewhat affected by rotation of object

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3735/599

Comment: Already attempted methods mentioned in issue: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3735/why-do-freestyle-outlines-occasionally-have-gaps

Did not solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have the Face Smoothness option enabled?  Do you also have the same problem if you change the camera from perspective to orthographic (and vice versa)?

Comment: Face Smoothness is enabled. 

Problem occurs in both Ortho and Persp.

Comment: What is the shading (either Flat or Smooth) in the problem area of the mesh data?  If the Smooth shading is used, do you also have the same problem when the shading of the problem area is changed to Flat?  What happens if you disable the Face Smoothness option?  I guess this issue is caused by an unknown bug related to line visibility.

Comment: The problem appeared at a point when some edge-hardening was applied. Smoothed, both with and without Face Smoothness, produced better results, but neither was usable. Additionally, I added more geometry around the tail-fin which helped, but did not solve the issue. 

I ended up going with a combo of all smooth shading + Face Smoothness disabled + Geometry > Backbone stretching. It helped hide the small gaps and didn't create any large ones. Did lead to a lot of errors extending outside the silhouette, but not too many within. This is obviously a work around & not a proper solution

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue, in my opinion this is a bug ocurring when working with larger geometries. Try scaling your geometry down (dimensions below 100 units) and try again.

For bigger geometries sometimes whole lines or part of lines (always when crossing with hidden lines as seen from the camera) are disappearing, this goes away when simply scaling down. See the screenshots below.

[image: Partly disappearing line in large geometry, hidden line shown for emphasis]

[image: Partly disappearing line in large geometry]

[image: The issue occurs when the geometry dimensions are >100 units, scaled down, the freestyle lines work as expected.]

I've file a bug report here, including a testfile: https://developer.blender.org/T49479

**Update:** According to the bug report, this bug has been fixed end of December 2016 and should not occur anymore in newer versions of blender.